# Get xy path coordinates of letters in a word

Tags: r, r-s4, grimport

I wish to use gganimate and tweener to morph some letters into other letters. Thus, I need a dataframe of x, y coordinates for each letter in a word as input to ggplot.

I'm not really sure how to do this, but my thinking is that library([grImport](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/grImport.pdf)) may help.

I created a Postscript file of the word "hello" by printing and then saving the output to Postscript. It's [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1n00m0wg4ctuidv/hello.ps?dl=0).

This code reads hello.ps

```
library(grImport)

PostScriptTrace("figures/hello.ps", "hello.xml")
hello <- readPicture("hello.xml")
grid.picture(hello)
```

hello is an S4 class object.

Am I correct in thinking that the structure of hello holds x,y coordinates for each letter of the the word "hello"?

If so, how do I extract those coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record the solution is:

```
# Extract x, y coordinates of path from S4 object of class Picture
# letters[i], i is the index into the word, "hello".

x <- hello@paths$text@letters[2]$path@x 
y <- hello@paths$text@letters[2]$path@y
```